# jprofiler: an error has occured during startup

Tags: jprofiler

I am trying to install jprofiler8 (8.0.3) (evaluation) on my Centos Release 6.4 (Final) machine but keep getting errors on start-up (error below).   Ive tried starting it from the installation wizard when it first offered to run it for me, as well as from the location that the documentation states to start it from ([jprofiler install directory]/bin/jprofiler) with the same result. I don't know if it's a matter of user error (that would be me) or compatibility.  If its the latter, do you know if there's a different version that would work opposed to 8.0.3? Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.FrontendApplication.M(ejt:722)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.FrontendApplication.b(ejt:691)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.FrontendApplication.main(ejt:1260)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.Launcher.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1269)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1244)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(SwingUtilities.java:1346)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.FrontendApplication.M(ejt:713)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass(I)Ljava/lang/Class;
    at com.jidesoft.plaf.UIDefaultsLookup.getCallerClassLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.jidesoft.plaf.UIDefaultsLookup.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.jidesoft.plaf.basic.BasicJideButtonUI.installDefaults(Unknown Source)
    at com.jidesoft.plaf.basic.BasicJideButtonUI.installUI(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:655)
    at com.jidesoft.swing.JideButton.updateUI(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.init(AbstractButton.java:2172)
    at javax.swing.JButton.<init>(JButton.java:136)
    at javax.swing.JButton.<init>(JButton.java:90)
    at com.jidesoft.swing.JideButton.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.jidesoft.swing.JideButton.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.jidesoft.swing.SimpleScrollPane$ScrollButton.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.jidesoft.swing.SimpleScrollPane.createScrollButton(Unknown Source)
    at com.jidesoft.swing.SimpleScrollPane.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.jidesoft.swing.SimpleScrollPane.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.i.a.u.<init>(ejt:101)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.i.a.q.e(ejt:101)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.i.a.q.c(ejt:32)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.i.c.b.a.<init>(ejt:15)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.i.c.b.b.P(ejt:432)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.i.c.b.b.<init>(ejt:87)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.i.c.v.j(ejt:1086)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.d.b.g.a(ejt:142)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.i.c.v.<init>(ejt:127)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.i.i.j(ejt:73)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.d.b.g.a(ejt:142)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.i.i.<init>(ejt:29)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.cn.B(ejt:459)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.cn.f(ejt:70)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.by.X(ejt:748)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.d.h.e(ejt:521)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.by.<init>(ejt:122)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.ah.run(ejt:716)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:241)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen with OpenJDK and will be fixed in 8.0.4. Please context support@ej-technologies.com to get a preliminary build or use the Oracle JRE.